# Is there any publicly available RESTful services that can be used for testing

Tags: json, api, rest, crud

Does anyone know of any publicly available RESTful services that can be used for testing. I'm not talking about software or browsers extensions. Just an online service that I can CRUD json data with using javascript. I'm testing a JS library's rest api and there's only so much I can do with static json data.

I'm guessing there's no such thing due to what's involved but I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to practice 'gets' you can use [cloudant](http://www.cloudant.com) as you can sign up for free.  however, there are restrictions on adding new documents from a cross domain ajax call.  I recommend running one locally.   I use [couchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/index.html)  very quick, very easy.

Comment: I forgot about couchDB. I'll use that. Thanks very much

Comment: @DefyGravity can you please provide more details about couchDB ? Any sample API requests / code which demostrate usage of fitnesse as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google feed api and pass in any rss url to test .

This may help you.

http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/reference.html#resultJson